# Charge device and power other devices over the same USB port

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, lipo

I'm creating a raspberry pi based mobile device. It has a LiPo-battery and a lipo charger, which will power the raspberry pi. The device should have one usb port, over which the device can be charged from externally. Furthermore, I want to be able to connect e.g. a keyboard over the same port, which means that the usb port has to be able to power external devices. I have researched a lot about bidirectional usb power but I couldn't find anything which helped me. I guess this is normal behaviour for every smartphone out there, somehow related schematics and controllers for this seem hard to find. I will include a schematic of my project.

[image]
schematic so far (the bottom left corner is a save shutdown for the rpi)

Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: uff, can you take another photo with less specular lighting?

Comment: Sorry, shopping questions are off-topic for this site. They become outdated very quickly.

Comment: sorry I have very bad light conditions on my whiteboard @MarcusMüller

Comment: I guess its not so much a shopping questions as a questions on how to do that at i.e. what usb protocol has to be used (usb pd? or usb otg?) @ElliotAlderson

Comment: OK, I will take out the shopping part.

Comment: For the future, if you have an image with poor lighting like that, a couple of minutes in a free image editor like GIMP can save a lot of time for people trying to read it. I used a high-pass filter, followed by brightness curves for a quick fix.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is generally powered via USB, while at the same time you can attach devices (such as keyboard or mice, but even a touchscreen) to its USB sockets. So it actually has all you need already built in, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PMF. Im building an embedded mobile system with a housing. I will be using the Compute Module 4. In my housing I only want to have 1 usb port. I know that this would be possible by connecting 2 usb ports i.e. the whole point of my questions is the number of usb ports to 1. Just think of it like I want to build a smartphone like device that only has 1 usb port (like any smartphone).